# using left and patindex to update information

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to update a column according to an existing column. The column to be updated is the Business. The existing column is the Deparment. Not all departments have the colon (:)

This is what I need to get:

Table 1

**Business         Department**

```
 Xerox         Xerox            
 Google        Google: Development
 Zas           Zas: Selling
 Worten        Worten
```

I have used T-SQL:

```
UPDATE Table 1
set business=left(Department,patindex('%:%',Department))
```

What I am getting:

**Business         Department**

```
               Xerox            
 Google:       Google: Development
 Zas:          Zas: Selling
               Worten
```

I have tried to put -1 after the patindex but this is forbidden. This would get rid of the colon .  So i need another approach to get rid of the colon and to enable the appearing of worten and xerox in the business column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE [Table 1]
set business=
case when patindex('%:%',Department)>0 then left(Department,patindex('%:%',Department)-1)
else Department
end;
```

Unless this is a step in cleaning up your data, you could also just create a computed column with the same expression.

Answer (score 1):

I would write this as:

```
update Table 1
    set business = left(Department, charindex(':', Department + ':') - 1);
```

First, I prefer `charindex()` over `patindex()`.  No doubt, this is because I have left the wildcards out of the pattern on more than one occasion.

Second, you can eliminate the conditional logic by just appending a colon at the end of the department.  That simplifies the logic.

Comment: @graphene . . . Good catch.  Thank you.